# C++ syntax - combination of conditional and arithmetic operators

Tags: c++, syntax

I have encountered in some algorithm shortened syntax for the first time:

```
j -= i < 3;
```

Can you please explain to me what it means

Answer (score 4):

The expression `i < 3` is a boolean expression. It's either `true` or `false`

In C++ `true` and `false` are implicitly convertible to the `int` values `1` and `0` (respectively).

So depending on the value of `i` it's either equal to

```
j -= 1;  // i < 3 is true
```

or

```
j -= 0;  // i < 3 is false
```

Answer (score 2):

It’s just a more terse way of writing:

```
if (i < 3)
    j = j - 1;
```

Comment: @Aconcagua: I'd be very surprised if any decent compiler from the last 10 years or so generated significantly different code for both alternatives. It's [easy enough to check though](https://godbolt.org/g/9rtkVn) - gcc 7.2 certainly generates pretty much identical code for both. And [clang generates exactly the same for both](https://godbolt.org/g/v2NgwR).

Answer (score -1):

J-=1<3    is a boolean expression . which means j=j - 1<3 . here the compiler will examine the comparison between 1 and 3 which is true . true means in c++ 1 so j=j - 1 . this expression is the same as j- -